# Thread synchronization problem with c++ std::atomic variables

Tags: c++11, atomic

The following program is giving me unexpected behavior when it's printing the "bad" output once in a while.  The two threads are supposed to synchronize using the two std::atomic variables 's_lock1' and 's_lock2'.  In func2, in order to set the 's_var' variable to 1, it must have atomically stored a non-zero value in 's_lock2' and the other thread (func1) must not have updated the 's_lock1' variable yet. However, somehow in func1 it's printing the unexpected "bad" output.  The s_lock2.load() statement seems to return false instead.  Is there something wrong with this code snippet?  Is it an issue related to memory ordering?

I am running this on an 8-core Linux server with Centos 7 installed.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <unistd.h>

std::atomic_uint s_lock1 = 0;
std::atomic_uint s_lock2 = 0;
std::atomic_uint s_var = 0;

static void func1()
{
    while (true) {
        s_lock1.store(1, std::memory_order_release);
        if (s_lock2.load(std::memory_order_acquire) != 0) {
            s_lock1.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
            continue;
        }
        if (s_var.load(std::memory_order_acquire) > 0) {
            printf("bad\n");
        }
        usleep(1000);
        s_lock1.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
    }
}

static void func2()
{
    while (true) {
        s_lock2.store(1, std::memory_order_release);
        if (s_lock1.load(std::memory_order_acquire) != 0) {
            s_lock2.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
            continue;
        }
        s_var.store(1, std::memory_order_release);
        usleep(5000);
        s_var.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
        s_lock2.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(func1);
    std::thread t2(func2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to have a bunch of unexpected characters, what did you paste it from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This locking algorithm may break because of the store buffers in Intel CPUs: the stores do not go into level 1 cache directly but are queued in the store buffer for a while and hence are invisible to another CPU during that time:

> To allow performance optimization of instruction execution, the IA-32 architecture allows departures from strong-ordering model called processor ordering in Pentium 4, Intel Xeon, and P6 family processors. **These processor-ordering variations (called here the memory-ordering model) allow performance enhancing operations such as allowing reads to go ahead of buffered writes.** The goal of any of these variations is to increase instruction execution speeds, while maintaining memory coherency, even in multiple-processor systems.

The store buffers need to be flushed for this locking to work by using [`std::memory_order_seq_cst`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Sequentially-consistent_ordering) for stores to locks (the default memory order for loads and stores, you can just do `s_lock1 = 1;`, for example). `std::memory_order_seq_cst` for stores causes the compiler generate `xchg` instruction or insert `mfence` instruction after the store, both of which make the effect of the store visible to other CPUs:

> Atomic operations tagged `memory_order_seq_cst` not only order memory the same way as release/acquire ordering (everything that happened-before a store in one thread becomes a visible side effect in the thread that did a load), but **also establish a single total modification order of all atomic operations that are so tagged**. Sequential ordering may be necessary for multiple producer-multiple consumer situations where all consumers must observe the actions of all producers occurring in the same order. Total sequential ordering requires a full memory fence CPU instruction on all multi-core systems. This may become a performance bottleneck since it forces the affected memory accesses to propagate to every core.

Working example:

```
std::atomic<unsigned> s_lock1{0};
std::atomic<unsigned> s_lock2{0};
std::atomic<unsigned> s_var{0};

void func1() {
    while(true) {
        s_lock1.store(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
        if(s_lock2.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst) != 0) {
            s_lock1.store(0, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
            continue;
        }
        if(s_var.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) > 0) {
            printf("bad\n");
        }
        usleep(1000);
        s_lock1.store(0, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    }
}

void func2() {
    while(true) {
        s_lock2.store(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
        if(s_lock1.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst) != 0) {
            s_lock2.store(0, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
            continue;
        }
        s_var.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        usleep(5000);
        s_var.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        s_lock2.store(0, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1(func1);
    std::thread t2(func2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: To prevent #StoreLoad reordering, the loads have to be tagged `mo_seq_cst` as well